# using uniRoot Package to solve nonlinear equations in R

Tags: r, math, machine-learning, data-science

I am trying to use uniRoot to solve the below equation in R

[Equation to solve - Assume Theta-F = 4 and Theta-L = 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUu7O.png)

Outlined in this paper.... http://dro.dur.ac.uk/11458/1/11458.pdf

I know my code is wrong [shown below] but cant figure out why...

```
# Choose Theta-F and Theta-L, e = 0.01

e=0.01
tehta_f = 2
theta_l = 4

# Solve for (v)

v <- log(theta_l)/(log(1/e-1))
print(v)
print(1-v)

# Solve (3) for b

our_function_new <- function(b){
  s <- (b+v-1)/(2*b+v-2)
  w <- ((e/s)^(b+v-1)*((1-e)/(1-s))^(b-1))
  return(w)
}

our_function_new <- Vectorize(our_function_new)
roots_our_function_new <- uniroot.all(our_function_new, c(0, 1-v))
roots_our_function_new
```

Uniroot returns "numeric(0)" --> I assume that means no roots. 
Not quite sure where i am going wrong

Comment: Your function `equation` returns a function, not a number, which presumably is needed in order to find the `x` for which `equation == 0`. Also, do not expect us to read the paper - tell us what variable you are trying to solve for. `sigma`? `w`? In addition, you seem to have a function `sigma` which needs an argument `b` which isn't defined anywhere, and you seem to use `sigma` as a number rather than a function?

Comment: Ok apologise for being a bit vague. I have amended the equation so hopefully now it will make a bit more sense. I am trying to solve for (b)... Sigma is a function that is substituted into the final equation, so i have renamed Sigma to (s). 
You definitely do not need to read the paper, i only put it up incase anyone was interested in the problem i am trying to solve. The imagine is really the only thing you need to look at.
Thank you so much for your help... really appreciate it

Comment: Thanks for cleaning it up. First, you should mention which package has `uniroot.all` in it so that people can replicate your example. Second, if you plot your function over the range `0, 1-v` you will so it has no roots there, so that's why none are found. Perhaps you have made a mistake in transcribing the equation, because essentially your function is A * B^(b) where A, B are constants, and I don't think equations of that form have zeros in `b` unless A or B are 0.